# Equivalence of two definitions. (Limit of functions)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In Principle of Mathematical Analysis(by Rudin), the definition of limit of function is given as:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces; suppose $E \subset X $, $f$ maps $E$ into $Y$, and $p$ is a limit point of $E$. We write $f(x) \rightarrow q$ as $x \rightarrow p$

if there is a point $q \in Y$ with the following property: For every $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists a $ \delta > 0 $ such that

$$ d_Y (f(x),p) < \epsilon $$

for all points $x \in E $ for which

$$0< d_X(x,p) < \delta $$

Now weather or not it is equivalent to:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces; suppose $E \subset X $, $f$ maps $E$ into $Y$, and $p$ is a limit point of $E$. We write $f(x) \rightarrow q$ as $x \rightarrow p$

if there is a point $q \in Y$ with the following property: For every $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists a $ \delta > 0 $ such that

$$f(N_{\delta}^0(p) \cap E) \subset N_{\epsilon}(q)$$

Here $ N_{\delta}^0(p) $ Denote a the deleted neighborhood of point $ p $ with radius $ \delta $

When I tried to prove I stuck at $ x \in A \implies f(x) \in f(A)$ but converse is not true.

If they are not equivalent, kindly provide a counterexample.

Comment: The condition '$f(N_{\delta}^0(p) \cap E) \subset N_{\epsilon}(q)$' is just a restatement of  the condition '$\forall x \in E: 0< d_X(x,p) < \delta \implies d_Y (f(x),p) < \epsilon$' in set-theoretic notation and is logically equivalent. Thus the two definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence is reached because for a $x\in N^0_{\delta}(p)\cap E$ means $x\in E$ and $0<d_X(x,p)<\delta$.

For such $x$ happens $f(x)\in N_{\epsilon}(q)$ which is meaning that $d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$.